# Laravel belongsTo relationship - Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

### User.php

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company');
    }
}
```

### Company.php

```
class Company extends Model
{
    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

### Table users

id name companies_id

### Table companies

id name

I'm trying to get the name of the company attached to the user.

```
$user = User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);
$companyName = $user->company()->first()->name;
```

I got this error message `Trying to get property of non-object`

I don't get what I'm missing... Thank you in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

By default, Eloquent is taking the name of the relationship + '_id' to guess the foreign key.

### Solution A

```
public function company() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'companies_id')
}
```

### Solution B

```
public function companies() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company')
}
```

Comment: You should use company_id to follow the convention. Check this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Both solution A and B still work great in Laravel 5.8. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Also it may be null your company_id field

That reason you must be check your field on the loop

f.e

```
foreach($users as $user) 
{
   if(isset($user->company->title)): 

     echo  $user->company->title;
   else:

     echo 'empty';
   endif;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it without the "first" method.

```
$companyName = $user->company()->name;
```